# Find n such that $A(1+r)^n=2A$

Tags: finance

> Suppose that you deposit  your money in a bank that pays interest at a nominal rate of 10% per year.  How long will it take for your money to double if the interest rate is compound?

Could you, please, check the correctness of my thoughts?

The condition above may be rephrasing as follows:

find n such that

$A(1+r)^n=2A$

Solution

$2-(1+r)^n=0$

$(1+r)^n=2$

$n=\log_{(1+r)}2$

Comment: You are correct! Well done. Use `\log` for $\log$

Comment: That looks good.  If encountered in real-life, where you actually needed to calculate this, you could use natural log for ease of using a calculator, with $n = \displaystyle \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(1+r)}$.

Comment: Oh. Thank you all.